# How to solve Infinite Re-rendering problem in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useSearchParams } from "next/navigation";
import { Map, MapMarker } from "react-kakao-maps-sdk";
import { useSwipeable } from "react-swipeable";
import { parseString } from "xml2js";

import { HospitalCard } from "../component/page";

const fetchSearchResults = (searchTerm, currentLocation) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    kakao.maps.load(() => {
      var places = new window.kakao.maps.services.Places();

      var callback = function (result, status) {
        if (status === window.kakao.maps.services.Status.OK) {
          const positions = result
            .filter((item) => item.category_name.includes("의료,건강"))
            .map((item) => {
              return {
                title: item.place_name,
                latlng: { lat: item.y, lng: item.x },
                address: item.address_name,
              };
            })
            // 10km 반경 내의 정보만 가져오게 필터링
            .filter((position) => {
              const distance = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(
                currentLocation.lat,
                currentLocation.lng,
                position.latlng.lat,
                position.latlng.lng
              );
              return distance <= 10;
            });
          resolve(positions);
        } else {
          reject(status);
        }
      };

      places.keywordSearch(searchTerm, callback);
    });
  });
};

const Popup = ({ position, onClose }) => (
  <div
    className="fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center z-10"
    style={{ backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)" }}
  >
    <div className="bg-white p-5">
      <h2>{position.title}</h2>
      <button onClick={onClose}>Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>
);

function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  var R = 6371; // Radius of the earth in km
  var dLat = deg2rad(lat2 - lat1); // deg2rad below
  var dLon = deg2rad(lon2 - lon1);
  var a =
    Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
    Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) *
      Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) *
      Math.sin(dLon / 2) *
      Math.sin(dLon / 2);
  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
  var d = R * c; // Distance in km
  return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {
  return deg * (Math.PI / 180);
}

const SearchResultList = ({ results }) => (
  <div className="results-list">
    {results.map((result, index) => (
      <SearchResult key={index} result={result} />
    ))}
  </div>
);

// 검색 결과 정렬 함수
const sortResults = (results, option) => {
  if (option === "desc") {
    return [...results].sort((a, b) => b.title.localeCompare(a.title));
  } else {
    return [...results].sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
  }
};

const SearchResultPage = () => {
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const [showList, setShowList] = useState(false);
  const [activeMarker, setActiveMarker] = useState(null);
  const [sortOption, setSortOption] = useState("asc"); // 정렬 옵션 상태
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");

  // url 쿼리 파라미터에서 검색어 가져오기
  const category = searchParams.get("category");
  const term = searchParams.get("term");
  const option = searchParams.get("option");
  useEffect(() => {
    if (option === "진단명") {
      getSearchResults(term);
    } else if (option === "병원명") {
      getSearchResults(term);
    } else {
      getSearchResults(category);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchResults(sortResults(searchResults, sortOption));
  }, [sortOption]); // 정렬 옵션이 변경될 때마다 검색 결과를 새로 정렬

  // 추가: 마커 클릭 핸들러
  const handleMarkerClick = (position) => {
    setActiveMarker(position);
  };

  // 추가: 팝업 닫기 핸들러
  const handleClosePopup = () => {
    setActiveMarker(null);
  };

  // 검색 결과 데이터
  // const searchResult = {
  //   title: '연세우리내과의원',
  //   category: '내과',
  //   distance: '1km',
  //   location: '서울 마포구 노고산동',
  // };

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    center: {
      lat: 37.55523269567481,
      lng: 126.92098259393505,
      // lat: 33.450701,
      // lng: 126.570667,
    },
    errMsg: null,
    isLoading: true,
  });

  const getSearchResults = async (searchTerm) => {
    if (searchTerm) {
      const results = await fetchSearchResults(searchTerm, state.center);
      setSearchResults(results);
      // 상태를 업데이트하여 지도에 새로운 마커 표시
      setPositions(results);
      console.log(searchResults);
    }
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    setSearchValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const clearSearchValue = () => {
    setSearchValue("");
    getSearchResults("");
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      getSearchResults(searchValue); // Add this line
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (option === "진단명") {
      setSearchValue(term);
      getSearchResults(term);
    } else if (option === "병원명") {
      setSearchValue(term);
      getSearchResults(term);
    } else {
      setSearchValue(term);
      getSearchResults(category);
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setSearchResults(sortResults(searchResults, sortOption));
  }, [sortOption]); // 정렬 옵션이 변경될 때마다 검색 결과를 새로 정렬

  useEffect(() => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      // GeoLocation을 이용해서 접속 위치를 얻어옵니다
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          setState((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            center: {
              lat: position.coords.latitude, // 위도
              lng: position.coords.longitude, // 경도
            },
            isLoading: false,
          }));
        },
        (err) => {
          setState((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            errMsg: err.message,
            isLoading: false,
          }));
        }
      );
    } else {
      // HTML5의 GeoLocation을 사용할 수 없을때 마커 표시 위치와 인포윈도우 내용을 설정합니다
      setState((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        errMsg: "geolocation을 사용할수 없어요..",
        isLoading: false,
      }));
    }
  }, []);

  const [positions, setPositions] = useState([
    {
      title: "서울본내과의원",
      latlng: { lat: 37.55523269567481, lng: 126.92098259393505 },
    },
    {
      title: "서울배내과의원",
      latlng: { lat: 37.501932339665, lng: 127.036088958468 },
    },
    {
      title: "속편한내과의원",
      latlng: { lat: 37.57527683230121, lng: 127.03776916889551 },
    },
  ]);

  async function getRegionCode(address) {
    const addressSplit = address.split(" ");
    let region = "";
    if (addressSplit[0] === "서울") {
      region = addressSplit[1];
    } else {
      region = addressSplit[0] + addressSplit[1];
    }
    const regionCode = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:3000/map/getRegion?name=${region}`
    );
    if (!regionCode.ok) {
      throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
    }

    return regionCode.json();
  }

  async function getHospitalCode(name, regionCode) {
    const hospital = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:3000/map/getHospital?name=${name}&sigunguCode=${regionCode}`
    );

    if (!hospital.ok) {
      throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
    }

    return hospital.json();
  }

  async function handleOnSearch(result) {
    const regionCode = await getRegionCode(result.address);
    const hospital = await getHospitalCode(result.title, regionCode);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://apis.data.go.kr/B551182/nonPaymentDamtInfoService/getNonPaymentItemHospDtlList?ykiho=${hospital.hospitalCode}&yadmNm=${hospital.name}&sgguCd=${hospital.sigunguCode}&ServiceKey=z8DBwSKYyrQmvrdRM3JHcnSnIH3qEB04vjhUdl7cldEloIgaGARHTLJE1A%2FFu7LqtfX8Ki7C1XphM589aBefMw%3D%3D`
      );
      const data = await response.text();
      return data;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  const handlers = useSwipeable({
    onSwipedUp: () => {
      setShowList(true);
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    },
    onSwipedDown: () => {
      setShowList(false);
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    },
    preventDefaultTouchmoveEvent: true,
    trackMouse: true,
  });

  const SearchResult = ({ result }) => {
    const [hospital, setHospital] = useState(null);
    const [hospitalJson, setHospitalJson] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      const fetchHospital = async () => {
        const data = await handleOnSearch(result);
        setHospital(data);
      };

      if (result !== hospital) fetchHospital();
    }, [result, hospital]);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (hospital) {
        parseString(hospital, function (err, results) {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
          }
          setHospitalJson(JSON.stringify(results));
        });
      }
    }, [hospital]);

    if (!hospitalJson) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>;
    }

    return <HospitalCard result={result} hospital={hospitalJson} />;
  };

  return (
    <div className="">
      {!state.isLoading && (
        <div className="flex drop-shadow-md bg-white p-2">
          <Link href="/">
            <img
              className="flex-initial p-2 pl-0"
              src="/arrow_left.png"
              alt="뒤로가기"
            />
          </Link>
          <input
            className="p-2 w-96 bg-slate-50"
            type="text"
            placeholder="검색어를 입력하세요"
            value={searchValue}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
          />
          {searchValue && (
            <img
              className="p-2 pl-3"
              src="/cancel.png"
              alt="지우기"
              onClick={clearSearchValue}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      )}

      {/* 페이지 중앙 지도 이미지 */}
      {!showList && (
        <div>
          {!state.isLoading && (
            // 지도를 표시할 Container
            <Map
              center={state.center}
              className="w-full h-96"
              level={9} // 지도의 확대 레벨
            >
              {positions.map((position, index) => (
                <MapMarker
                  key={index}
                  position={position.latlng}
                  onClick={() => handleMarkerClick(position)}
                />
              ))}
              {/* 내 위치 표시하는 마커 추가 */}
              {!state.isLoading && (
                <MapMarker
                  position={state.center}
                  content={"내 위치"}
                  onClick={() =>
                    handleMarkerClick({
                      title: "내 위치",
                      latlng: state.center,
                    })
                  }
                />
              )}
            </Map>
          )}
        </div>
      )}

      {/* 페이지 하단 검색 결과 */}
      <div className="bg-slate-50 pl-2 pr-2" {...handlers}>
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between p-2">
          <h2>Results</h2>
          <select
            value={sortOption}
            onChange={(e) => setSortOption(e.target.value)}
          >
            <option value="asc">오름차순</option>
            <option value="desc">내림차순</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        {showList ? (
          searchResults.map((result, index) => (
            <SearchResult key={index} result={result} />
          ))
        ) : option === "병원명" && searchResults.length > 0 ? (
          searchResults
            .slice(0, 1)
            .map((result, index) => (
              <SearchResult key={index} result={result} />
            ))
        ) : searchResults.length > 0 ? (
          searchResults
            .slice(0, 2)
            .map((result, index) => (
              <SearchResult key={index} result={result} />
            ))
        ) : (
          <div>결과 없음</div>
        )}
      </div>

      {/* 추가: activeMarker가 있을 때 팝업 렌더링 */}
      {activeMarker && (
        <Popup position={activeMarker} onClose={handleClosePopup} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchResultPage;
```

I am developing my site with nextjs. It has very low speed and is re-rendered infinitely.

in line 157, console.log is operating infinitely. I think this page is re-rendering infintely. I want to know how to fix it. Thank you everyone.

I did modify useEffect but it didn't work. And I think when my code modify state, it re-render. but I dont know where to fix. I need some help.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please minimize example. Reduce your code line by line, it will help you with understanding issue, and it will also help others to provide better answer.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).